# Find all possible mime type of a file

Tags: security, mime, steganography

How can we find all possible mimetype of a file ?

Why do I want to do that : when openning a file of a source you can't trust you have to be extra careful.

**Example:**

Here an image which is also a zip file [link to the image of google logo which is also a zip file containing a txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RTc.png). If you open it you will see the google logo but if you rename it with `.zip` extension and open it will reveal a text file.

I want to find something that can tell me this file could be a `image/png` or `application/zip`, do anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find those file types using the `file -k` command, however after you unzip using GNU `unzip` you get this:

```
Archive:  Z3RTc.zip
warning [Z3RTc.zip]:  13504 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
 extracting: lol.txt
```

So yeah, with ~13K of "trash" at the start of the `.zip` file, it will be tricky to find an application that guesses that it is a `.zip` file (other than `unzip` itself, apparently).